# Genesis Responsive Slider Img Center

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, responsive-design

I'm trying to get the image in the Genesis responsive slider to center, and thus far I have failed miserably. I've created a widget area on my hompage and initialized it with:

```
function tx_slider_genesis(){
genesis_widget_area( 'slider-1', array(
'before' => '<div class="slider1 center">',
'after' => '</div>',
) );
}
```

The homepage is here:
www.testing.tx0rx0.com

I thought that I could nest CSS such that the img tag in the slider1 div could be centered by doing:

```
.slider1 .img{
float:center;
}
```

But I don't really understand nested CSS and its not presently working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see how your HTML code is structured. Try this:

```
.slider1 .img{
text-align:center;
}
```

If that doesn't work, try changing .img to img as follows:

```
.slider1 img{
text-align:center;
}
```

Let me know how it works out.
Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I tried those and it didn't work. Still looking for the answer on this one.

Comment: The slider is controlled by the Genesis Responsive SLider PLugin, which was placed in a widget area right below the header. If that helps anyone

Comment: Can you view source and copy and paste what is inside the "slider1" div and put it into a comment? I need to see what is in there.

Comment: I figured it out. The plugin's style.css overrode the main style.css Doing .flexslider{
margin: 0 auto !important;
} overrode the plugin and centered the image. Thanks, I'm sure that would have worked if not for the wordpress/plugin relationship